# I am trying to dowload a csv in python but all i get is weird symbols

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I am trying to download this csv in this link when i download with the browser it's ok but the code I can't
https://www.policyuncertainty.com/media/Global_Policy_Uncertainty_Data.csv
I have tried using pandas with utf-8 and latin-1:

If I do it without encoding I get this error : 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf5 in position 5: invalid start byte

```py
data = pd.read_csv('https://www.policyuncertainty.com/media/Global_Policy_Uncertainty_Data.csv',encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

I also tried with this code

```py
url = "https://www.policyuncertainty.com/media/Global_Policy_Uncertainty_Data.csv"
response = requests.get(url)        

with open(ruta+"/Global_Policy_Uncertainty_Data.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in response.iter_lines():
        print(line)
        writer.writerow(line.decode("ISO-8859-1").split("",""),escapechar="/")
```

but I always get this weird symbols in the file
probably because I don't have the right encoding, but when I use postman it gives me a normal data

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). The screen shot looks like random binary; is the data compressed?

Comment: Encoding is utf-8

Comment: This page is UTF8, like almost all web sites. It's just text, not some kind of binary encoding.

Comment: Why don't you just save the file to disk and use it? It's already a CSV file, it doesn't need any processing. Besides, if it's UTF8, `line.decode("ISO-8859-1")` will only mangle non-US text

Comment: The link is to an image of a CSV, not an actual CSV file.

Comment: Some Unicode files start with a BOM - a couple of bytes that specify what kind of Unicode encoding is used. That's the only way to really tell that a file is UTF8 and not some eg Swedish file with 2KB of ASCII text suddenly followed by some Swedish characters. Try using readv_csv with `utf8-sig` as the encoding.

Comment: @diegocornejot that error doesn't mean the file is Latin1. All single-byte codepages are identical to UTF8 in the range 0x00-0x7F which covers US-English letters, numbers and some symbols. There's no way to say that the file you posted is UTF8 or Latin1 if all characters are English letters and numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing https to http in the url solved the issue for me:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('http://www.policyuncertainty.com/media/Global_Policy_Uncertainty_Data.csv')
```

The issue could be from due to an invalid URL scheme. From pandas read_csv documentation: 'Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, gs, and file.